# How to connect vscode to Python API of webots?

Tags: python

I am working on a simulation project of robot with webots. Considering the internal complier of webots is not quite convenient for debug so that I am looking for some methods connecting the Python API to the third-party IDEs, one of which is vscode that I used before.
The only problem for now is how to correctly import the libs of Python API for webots simulation because I keep failed to run the code by the error:

```
No module named 'controller'
```

and my code can be displayed below:

```
...
from controller import Robot, DistanceSensor, Motor

# step 1: set supreme parameters

# create the Robot instance.
robot = Robot()

# get the time step of the current world.
timestep = int(robot.getBasicTimeStep())
...
```

Of course, this is a simple error report for missing the folder named 'controller' with the APIs named 'Robot' etc. However, the crutial problem is that I don't know to make vscode correctly find the path of webots Python API and import it. During this process, I have tried to set systemic environment variables toward the API path but nothing changed. Besides, I have tried to learn the tutorials from the offical address but the IDEs introduced in the tutorials do not vscode. Perhaps the thoughts are similar but the setting selections will vary in different IDEs. I really hope someone to help me to deal with it. Many thanks!

Comment: did you see the section on starting with pycharm.  I would start there. https://cyberbotics.com/doc/guide/using-your-ide#pycharm

Comment: @JonSG Yes, I have finished it. Now I am trying to implement the joint debugging with webots and vscode according to the analogous thoughts the tutorials gave. Instead of setting tabs, in vscode you can only achieve the configuration with json files. I don't know what those key means and how to make it correctly work on the importing.

Comment: @JonSG Oh, besides, I have successfully run the controller on PyCharm according to the tutorials but not on vscode.

Answer (score 0):

Webots simply executes the python file in the `controllers` folder of the same name, for instance `controller/somename/somename.py` from the folder containing that file (`controllers/somename`).

To replicate that behaviour in VSCode you need to set the `cwd` option. Go to the debug pane and click on the option to create `launch.json` if present. Then in the editor pane, click on `launch.json` and add or edit the following line `"cwd": "${fileDirname}"`, for instance here is mine:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "justMyCode": true
        }
    ]
}
```

And then for linting, add the path to `settings.json` (in the `.vscode` folder also):

```
{
    "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
        "C:/Program Files/Webots/lib/controller/python"
    ]
}
```

(In the case of windows, it seems like the environment variable `WEBOTS_HOME` isn't set, so you'll need to write the full path. If you work on a project with a team you will need to create it yourself.)